# Issue in sending mail for customer and to other mails using magento

Tags: magento-1.8

Created the form with fields and added the email code for sending the mail.But I need to send the mail with two different bodies

How can I send Please help me.

## My Mail code:

```
  <?php
   function sendMailAction(){
 //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);


 $cname=$_POST['cname'];
 $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];

  $html=
  '
  <p>City: '.$city.'</p>
  <p>Location: '.$location.'</p>
   <p>Name: '.$cname.'</p>
  <p>Email : '.$email.'</p>
  <p>Mobile Number: '.$mobile.'</p>'


 ;
  $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
  $mail->setToName($name);
  $mail->setToEmail('some.example@mail.com');
  $mail->setBody($html);
  $mail->setSubject('Booking');
  $mail->setFromEmail('some.example@mail.com');
  $mail->setFromName("example");

 $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

 try {
 $mail->send();
  //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is successfully Completed');
 //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
 return '<h2>Your Order has been submitted. Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';
//$this->_redirect('');
}
 catch (Exception $e) {
//Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
 //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 
//$this->_redirect('');
}
}
 function sendMailcustomerAction(){
 //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
  $email=$_POST['email'];

  $city=$_POST['city'];
  $location=$_POST['location'];

 $cname=$_POST['cname'];
 $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];

$html=
''

 ;
  $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
  $mail->setToName($name);
  $mail->setToEmail($email);
  $mail->setBody($html);
  $mail->setSubject('Booking');
  $mail->setFromEmail('Your mail');
  $mail->setFromName("somename");

  $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

   try {
   $mail->send();
   //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is    successfully Completed');
 //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
  return 'Your Order is Successfully Completed';
  //$this->_redirect('');
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
  //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
 //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
 return 'Unable to send.'; 
 //$this->_redirect('');
 }
 }
   echo sendMailcustomerAction();
   echo sendMailAction();
   ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create two function one is send to customer and other is send to owner or else you want to send

```
function sendMailAction(){
 //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
 $email=$_POST['email'];
  $name=$_POST['testname'];
  $city=$_POST['city'];
  $location=$_POST['location'];

 $cname=$_POST['cname'];
 $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];

  $html=
  '<p>TestName: '.$name.'</p>
  <p>City: '.$city.'</p>
  <p>Location: '.$location.'</p>
   <p>Name: '.$cname.'</p>
  <p>Email : '.$email.'</p>
  <p>Mobile Number: '.$mobile.'</p>'


 ;
  $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
  $mail->setToName($name);
  $mail->setToEmail('admin@labwise.in');
  $mail->setBody($html);
  $mail->setSubject('Booking');
  $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
  $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
//$mail->addBcc("admin@labwise.in");
 $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

 try {
 $mail->send();
  //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is successfully Completed');
 //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
 return '<h2>Your Order has been submitted. Thank you for using labwise.   </h2>';
//$this->_redirect('');
}
 catch (Exception $e) {
//Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
 //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
return '</h2>Unable to submit.</h2>'; 
//$this->_redirect('');
}
}
 function sendMailcustomerAction(){
 //Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999);
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $name=$_POST['testname'];
  $city=$_POST['city'];
  $location=$_POST['location'];

 $cname=$_POST['cname'];
 $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];

$html=
'<p>Dear'.$name.' ,

    We have received your order for '.$name.' . You will be attended shortly.

    Best Regards.
    Team Labwise.</p>'

 ;
  $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
  $mail->setToName($name);
  $mail->setToEmail($email);
  $mail->setBody($html);
  $mail->setSubject('Booking');
  $mail->setFromEmail('admin@labwise.in');
  $mail->setFromName("Labwise");
 //$mail->addBcc("contact@labwise.in");
  $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

   try {
   $mail->send();
   //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Order is    successfully Completed');
 //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
  return 'Your Order is Successfully Completed';
  //$this->_redirect('');
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
  //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
 //Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl());
 return 'Unable to send.'; 
 //$this->_redirect('');
 }
 }
   echo sendMailcustomerAction();
   echo sendMailAction();
```

Comment: When I click on the submit button it should send the mails to both.Is it possible with the above code.

Comment: Should I need to add the same code in the same file for both owner and customer.

Comment: yes you can add it will send your both emails

Comment: I am not getting any mails.Can you please check it

Comment: I had edited my code as you said.Please check it and suggest me if any thing is wrong.

Comment: did you get the message the email are sent?

Comment: No,I had not get the any message.

Comment: did you get any error on page?

Comment: No error it is showing empty page without any message.

Comment: check you error log for errors

Comment: I have checked the error logs.But no error in the log

Comment: update the answer replace with your code

Comment: Working but it showing the message twice "Your Order is succecsfully submitted"

Comment: yes remove the return from this function sendMailAction

Comment: If I remove.How I could I know the mail is sent or not

Comment: the customer email will be problem so remove from owner so you can see one email are send

Comment: Can't we override the problem.

Comment: how you want to display it

Comment: It has to get the same message but.There should not be any problem for both customer and owner for receiving mails.

Comment: you have to show the customer message not the owner message to user screen so the message will be display for customer